# listview databind alphabetical order

Tags: c#, listview, data-binding, alphabetical

I need to order my Category titles -

( <%#Eval("CategoryDescription").ToString().ToUpper()%>   )

Alphabetically.  How do I do this? Thanks!

Here is the code behind in C#:

```
    protected void lstvwFileCategory_OnItemDataBound(Object sender,   
    ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            ListViewDataItem temp = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
            Files.HAHADocument_Category catdata =   
            (Files.HAHADocument_Category)temp.DataItem;

            ListView files = new ListView();
            files = (ListView)e.Item.FindControl("lstvwFiles");

            files.DataSource = catdata.Documents;
            files.DataBind();
        }
     }
```

Here is the code itself:

```
     <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lstvwFileCategory"  
     OnItemDataBound="lstvwFileCategory_OnItemDataBound">
          <LayoutTemplate>
              <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
          </LayoutTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
               <div class="linksection">
                    <h2><%#Eval("CategoryDescription").ToString().ToUpper()%></h2>
                    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lstvwFiles"  
                    OnItemDataBound="lstdvwFiles_OnItemDataBound">
                         <LayoutTemplate>
                             <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
                         </LayoutTemplate>
               </div>
          </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:ListView>
```

and

```
 if (PageID > 0)
    {
        HAHA_BLL.FileRepository.Files fls = new HAHA_BLL.FileRepository.Files();
        lstvwFileCategory.DataSource =  
        fls.GetHAHADocument_Categories((int)PageID);
        lstvwFileCategory.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that populates `lstvwFileCategory`?

Comment: If I have Apples and Oranges, currently it's looking at the fact Oranges is ID 23, say, and Apples is ID 498. So the order is flipped. I just need it to look at the first letter and alphabetize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the code behind file, then change the data source assignment to this:

```
lstvwFileCategory.DataSource = fls.GetHAHADocument_Categories((int)PageID)
                                    .OrderBy(c => c.CategoryDescription);
```